# How to encode protobuf map in python?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using protobuf and grpc as interface between a client and server.
The server is written in C and the client uses python to communicate to the server.

I have a message created in protobuf like below.

```
message value_obj {
    uint32 code = 1;
    uint32 value = 2;
}

message list_of_maps {    
    map<uint32, value_obj> mapObj1 = 1;    
    map<uint32, value_obj> mapObj2 = 2; 
}
```

I tried creating objects in Python like below:

```
obj = list_of_maps()
mapObjToStore = value_obj()
mapObjToStore.code = 10
obj.mapObj1[1].CopyFrom(mapObjToStore)
```

When I try to receive the message in server, I get wrong values (huge numbers!).
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using python dictionary for that:

```
map1 = {}
obj1 = value_obj()
map1[1] =  obj1
map2 = {}
listOfMaps = list_of_maps(mapObj1=map1, mapObj2=map2)
```

Comment: what is dat func? `list_of_maps()`. Should I import it from somewhere?

Comment: @mrmailperson It's proto message from the question: `message list_of_maps { `